# Limit the selection to the visible object (in object mode)

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

If I have one object hidden behind another, clicking the visible one multiple times in Object mode alternates the selection between the two. Is it possible to turn this behaviour off, and make the selection stick to the visible object regardless of how many times I click it, similar to Limit selection to visible in Edit mode?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but I took the liberty to edit it to try to make it clearer. If I misunderstood it, or you otherwise disagree with my edits, you are welcome to [roll them back](http://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/26056/revisions).

Comment: This is expected and _useful_ I might add behavior, I don't think it can be altered. Really helpful when you have a cluttered scene as you can purposely click the same object several times to pick something behind or nearby.

Comment: You can also hold down alt to get a menu of objects to select, but I don't believe you can disable the cycle through objects behaviour.

Comment: I also think this is a strange request, since the current behavior got its advantages. I don't understand why you want to click many times to select it, or at least you can give a spcific example here.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about this button in edit mode?
[image: The Button]
No, I don't think there's an object mode equivalent. I don't see how it would be very useful, however, what's the problem?